# TypeError: Cannot read property 'headersSent' of undefined when using Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

app.js

```
var adminRouter = require('./routes/adminportal/home');
    app.use('/portal/admin', adminRouter)(passport);
    module.exports = app;
```

passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var mysql = require('mysql');
var dbconfig = require('../routes/db.js');


    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });


    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        db(function(err,conn){
            conn.query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id = ? ",[id], function(err, rows){
                done(err, rows[0]);
            });
        })
    });


    passport.use(
        'local-login',
        new LocalStrategy({

            usernameField : 'user_name',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true 
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {
            db(function(err,conn){
                conn.query("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE email_address = ?",[username], function(err, rows){
                    if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (!rows.length) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'bulunamadi.')); 
                }


                if (password != rows[0].password)
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'yanlis parola.'));


                return done(null, rows[0]);
                })
            }) 
        })
    );

    module.exports = passport;
```

home.js

```
module.exports = function(passport){
  /* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.session.userId != null){
    message = '';
    //res.render('dashboard',{message:message});
    res.render("adminportal/login.ejs");
  }else{
    var message = '';
    var sess = req.session; 
    res.render('adminportal/login.ejs',{message:message});   
  }
});
return router;
}
```

so whenever I try to run `localhost5000:/portal/admin` it returns the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'headersSent' of undefined`

I am stuck and been trying to implement passport.js for hours and it is my first time setting up Passport.js. Am I doing it wrongly ? I have tried to google for the error but no relevant results. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The *passport* parameter should be used with the require function not the app.use() function so your code in app.js file will be:

`var adminRouter = require('./routes/adminportal/home')(passport);
    app.use('/portal/admin', adminRouter);
    module.exports = app;`